# Google Sheet: How to determine where I should put arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I understand some basic usages of `Arrayformula`, but when it comes to complex formulas, I often get confused and don't know where to put it.

**Products:**

| ID | Name | init Stock | Current Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Bag | 24 | What arrayformula should I put in this cell? |
| 43 | Book | 45 | =C3 + SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A3,'Records'!B2:B = "in")) - SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A3,'Records'!B2:B = "out")) **//a normal formula** |
| 31 | Table | 42 | =ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C + SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "in")) - SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "out")) **//This doesn't work** |

**Records**

| ID | in/out | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | in | 1 |
| 43 | in | 34 |
| 31 | out | 5 |
| 23 | out | 13 |
| 23 | in | 14 |
| 23 | in | 111 |

I am using the above tables to track stock of products, when a new in/out records is added to the `Records` table, the value in Current Stock should change accordingly.

In the table above I put my attempt but it doesn't work, returning error saying filter's range mismatch. I guess I will have to wrap another `arrayformula` around `SUM` and/or `filter`. This is when confusion starts.
How do I determine where I should put another `arrayformula`?
As far as I understand, when inside an `arrayformula`, some functions that would originally take one value as parameter can take an array as parameter, but some others can't. How do I know which functions have this behavior?

Comment: If you want more knowledge in general on how to use arrayformula, you accessing tutorials and blogs e.g.: [coupler blog](https://blog.coupler.io/arrayformula-google-sheets/), [benlcollins](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/), [coefficient](https://coefficient.io/how-to-use-the-arrayformula-function-in-google-sheets/), [Sheetgo](https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/arrayformula-google-sheets/), [spreadsheetpoint](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/google-sheets-array-formula-guide/) or [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/805792/arrayformula-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in order to better explain how to use ARRAYFORMULA, but it always get tricky when you need to use it with formulas that already include ranges. I recommend you to investigate about [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) an BYCOL, basically they iterate a formula for a whole range row by row or column by column. Try this:

```
=BYROW(Records!C2:C,lambda(each,each + SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "in")) - SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "out"))))
```

Comment: THANKS! `BYROW` seems to be the right way to go. However, if the first parameter of byrow is something like A2:A, it seems that it will have an impact on the performance since it will execute for every row even though it is empty.

Comment: I'm glad! You can add a first condition in order to avoid the calculations if its empty: =BYROW(Records!C2:C,lambda(each,if(each="","",each + SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "in")) - SUM(filter('Records'!C2:C,'Records'!A2:A = A2:A,'Records'!B2:B = "out")))))

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking if I can do something like `Records!C2:C&COUNTIF(C2:C,"<>")` to make sure only rows with actual content are supplied to the lambda. Of course it doesn't work, and for that I've made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74494736/google-sheet-how-to-refer-to-a-range-using-a1notation-with-a-variable

Comment: Answered there about the use of INDIRECT ;)

Comment: Thanks. It seems `Byrow` is a newly added function, isn't it? I've never heard of it before this day.

Comment: Yes! Learned from it here about two weeks ago! It was released in [2022](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/byrow-function/#:~:text=The%20QUERY%20Function-,BYROW%20Function%20in%20Google%20Sheets%20%E2%80%93%20LAMBDA,Function%20(New%20For%202022!)&text=The%20BYROW%20function%20in%20Google,lambda%20function%20on%20that%20row.)