# Google Sheet: How to refer to a range using A1notation with a variable?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
A2:A&COUNTIF(A2:A,"<>")
```

Instead of simply `A2:A`, I am trying to build a A1Notation that would only refer to column A that contains actual content. (There won't be empty rows in between non-empty rows)
But this doesn't work. I need to use this A1notation as the first parameter of a `Filter` function.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTIF(A2:A,"<>"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking for all nonempty cells in A2:A, I'm not sure why you can't just use:

```
=filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=A2:INDEX(A2:A, COUNTA(A2:A))
```